# Using MVC2, how do I validate that a date is within a given date range?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime, update-attributes

I have a requirement, in an MVC2 web application, to validate that the user is at least 13 years old.  Is there a date/datetime validation attribute that will enable me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not "really" validating a date, you're validating based an equation (Today - Date > 13), you'll probably have to write [a custom validation attribute.](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) Something like this (this is just a back-of-the-napkin example).

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class AgeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public int MinAge { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(DateTime value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return DateTime.Now.Subtract(value).TotalDays > (MinAge * 365.25);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will use a generic age calculation instead of based on days.